# Android: How should I handle configuration changes in this scenario?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-activity

I'm writing an Android app that offers syntax highlighting for source code. Since I want it to handle large files fast, I made the syntax highlighting task non-blocking. I can't run the task on a separate thread because it modifies the UI, but it's also CPU intensive because it calls `SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan()` thousands of times.

The approach I took to this problem was design the task to do small batches of work at a time, and in between them, yield and let input/rendering code run. Here is a rough model of what my code looks like (I didn't write my app in Java):

```
void onCreate() {
    workLoop();
}

void workLoop() {
    // For those of you familiar with C#, the actual code was like
    // while (true)
    // {
    //     DoSmallBatchOfCpuIntensiveWork();
    //     await Task.Yield();
    // }

    doSmallBatchOfCpuIntensiveWork();
    Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiThreadHandler.post(() -> workLoop());
}
```

I've come across a problem while trying to handle configuration changes. I've realized that Android destroys and re-creates your Activity when you rotate the screen. I don't want to re-highlight the whole source code file when the user does this; if I'm in the middle of highlighting, I want to simply pick up where I left off. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't run the task on a separate thread because it modifies the UI

There are a handful of ways to run tasks off of the UI thread but still update the UI. Among them are (1) create an `AsyncTask` and update your UI from its callbacks, (2) create a `Service` and update your UI via broadcasts, and (3) manual multi-threading using a handler to post updates to your UI. Of course there are others, though they mostly fall into the realm of making (3) easier for you by abstracting (part of) it away.

> if I'm in the middle of highlighting, I want to simply pick up where I left off. How do I accomplish this?

I think the best (and simplest) thing to do is use `AsyncTask` to do your work, and host the `AsyncTask` inside a retained `Fragment`. This blog post is a great intro to retained fragments: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html